# How to allow redirect in Next.js only after reCaptcha

Tags: reactjs, next.js, recaptcha, next-router

I have a Next.js app, index page contains only captcha, and after successfull entry redirects to form at mydomain.com/form and that works just fine.
But also i can just enter in browser

> mydomain.com/form

and get to it without captcha, which i obviously dont want.

Is there a way to restrict all entries except redirect from captcha page? Found only solutions with logins, e.t.c which i dont need.

Im using react-google-recaptcha package

Here is my index page

```
function Captcha() {
  const reRef = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Подтвердите, что вы не робот</h1>
      <ReCAPTCHA
        sitekey={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}`}
        size="normal"
        ref={reRef}
        onChange={() => router.push('/form')}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this [guide](https://dev.to/shubhamverma18/implement-protected-routes-in-nextjs-37ml).

TL:DR Basically im adding a token to local storage after successful captcha, token is necessary to access form page.

Created a HOC named withAuth

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const withAuth = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return (props: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes) => {
    // checks whether we are on client / browser or server.
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      const Router = useRouter();

      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

      // If there is no access token we redirect to "/" page.
      if (!accessToken) {
        Router.replace("/");
        return null;
      }

      // If this is an accessToken we just render the component that was passed with all its props

      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }

    // If we are on server, return null
    return null;
  };
};



export default withAuth;
```

Changed captcha page to clean local storage on every load and put a token in after successful entry.

```
    function Captcha() {
  const reRef = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null);
  const router = useRouter()
  if(process.browser){localStorage.clear()}
  
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1>Подтвердите, что вы не робот</h1>
      <ReCAPTCHA
        sitekey={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY}`}
        size="normal"
        ref={reRef}
        onChange={() => 
          {
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken" , "1"),
            router.push('/form')
          }
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Captcha;
```

And passed my form component to withAuth
(changed from export default Home)

```
export default withAuth(Home);
```

Comment: Answers that are little more than only a link are not encouraged in SO. Consider adding the solution in your answer and keeping the link only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is same with that of authorizing restricted page based on authentication context.

In this case, create a [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that contains the state whether reCaptcha validation has been done. Then use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) in your form component to either render or redirect based on the state provided by the
reCaptcha context